# Keeping Scripting Dictionary in memory, VBA

Tags: windows, excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using a scripting dictionary in VBA to hold 1,840,000 key and value pairs in Excel 2010. I want to declare and populate them once, then use them in my modules and functions.

For starters, I declared the dictioanry as public, using `Public dict As Scripting.Dictionary`, then I populated it on `worksheet_activate()`.  How do I save it and use it in other mods?

Thank you

Comment: either public in a module as ash said, either pass it as argument to the Subs/functions. The good stuff would be to not lose the dictionaries on break/error...

Comment: @A.S.H I named a public sub "workbook_activate()" and it didn't run when the workbook opened. however, when I used "worksheet_activate()" it was great as long as my mods were still in that sheet/mod file.  Once I left, it appears the values within the dictionary get wiped.

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier are you implying that normally the dictionary would wipe on an error?

Comment: @A.S.H workbook.open*

Comment: Anything which resets your VBA project (eg an unhandled error, using `End`) will result in any global/static variables being lost.

Comment: @TimWilliams Isn't that an additional reason for using a getter function?

Comment: @A.S.H - no disagreement: I was responding to the OP's question above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a good programming practice, wrap such a variable in a getter function, and hide the global variable as a *static* local inside it. Populate it on first use.

To do that, write this function inside a standard module:

```
Public Function getMyDictionary() as Scripting.Dictionary
    Static dict as Dictionary ' static: will keep state across different calls

    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = new Scripting.Dictionary
        ''''''''''''''''''''
        dict.Add "foo", "bar"
        ' etc...
        ' Code to populate dictionary
        '
        ''''''''''''''''''''
    End If
    Set getMyDictionary = dict
End Function
```

Now whenever you need to reference the dictionary, simply type something like this:

```
If getMyDictionary.Exists("foo") Then doStuff
```

This idiom has many advantages:

- the dictionary is populated on first use. If during an Excel session it is not needed, it will not be populated.
- you no longer need to worry about *"when do I populate my dictionary."* It will be available and populated whenever and wherever it is needed
- if the project unloads due to some runtime error, all global variables are reset. In particular, objects are reset to `Nothing`. The wrapper function handles correctly the situation and re-populates the dictionary in a transparent way.
- TLDR... the global dictionary is hidden, access to it is (to some extent) controlled. "To some extent" because other code can still manipulate it (do insert, remove...). If one needs more control over it, for example allow other code to only read it, then make it a private member of some *Class Module* that exposes only the allowed functionality...

Comment: How would it evaluate "foobar", what purpose does this add?

Isn't/shouldn't a boolean getMyDictionary be enough?

Comment: @wizlog Great, but dont forget `Set dict = new Scripting.Dictionary`, I just added it :)

Comment: A.S.H., as soon as I run a sub located in another object (read: sheet) I loose access to the dictionary I just created and populated in the function you posted... despite it being static.

Comment: @wizlog what do you mean by you loose access? Make sure you put the function in a *Standard Code Module*, and always use it with the name `getMyDictionary`. Of course you can use another name for the function, but consider its name as the name of your dictionary in all other code.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, and thank you for being so helpful. By "loose access" I mean "dict is nothing" would return true, and it would need to recreate itself.  I simply assumed the space in memory was overridden.

Comment: @wizlog that happens if the VBA projects unloads. That is, if you stop execution of code in the debugger, or a runtime error has occured. But in a normal working session it will stay alive.

Comment: Thank you, I'll continue testing and mark the answer as correct when finished. (in the mean time just +1 :) ).  Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @wizlog okay thanks. It's a huge dictionary so please report back, I'm curious to know how it goes :)

Comment: Because you defined this as a function, should I use it within my worksheets themselves, i.e. should I be able to set cell c3 equal to getDictionary(a3)?

Comment: @wizlog As it is made the function is a VBA function returning a dictionary. To use the dictionary's capabilities within cell formulas, you still need to write some *UDF* (User-Defined-Function) that uses it.